# Persisting the dictionary index after deleting item

Tags: python, dictionary

I am iterating through dictionary, if some condition match, then I delete the dictionary item. Now dictionary dynamically index gets updated.

e.g.

```
{u'Titanic': {'match': [{'category': u'Book'},
                        {'category': u'Movie'},
                        {'category': u'Product'}],
              'score': 100}}
```

While iterating `match`, if I delete `Book` (index - 0), so now during next iteration it is showing me `product` (index - 1) directly, considering `movie` on index-0. It consider index-0 already iterated.

code snipped:

```
    for k1,v1 in enumerate(value['match']):
        if k1 != '':
            print '\n Category: ',k1,' ',v1['category']

            print 'Do you want to change the class of entity',k1 ,'? Y/N', 'Or delete', k1, '1/0' 
            choice = raw_input()
            if choice == 'N' or choice == 'n':
                pass
            elif choice == 'Y' or choice == 'y' :
                print '\tEnter class : \t'
                v1['category'] = raw_input()
                tagged = string.replace(sentence, key, v1['category'])
                tagged_ans.append(tagged)
            elif choice == '1':
                del v1['category']
                del value['match'][k1]
```

In such case how to persist current index and iterating without skipping any of the item. In above example item  `movie` get skipped

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @RikVerbeek: sorry, updated the question

Comment: don't delete the keys in dictionary, you are updating the dict and also increasing the counter simultaneously that's why pointer moves to 3rd item in 2nd iterate.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay: I am not much expert in this, but I want to ignore the item if not correctly tagged. Can you suggest any other solution if there

Comment: @puncrazy why don't you replace the item that you are deleting with blank dictinary.

Comment: I dont want to consider element, so dont know replacing it will help me or not. can you please give somehint, how

Answer (score 1):

You may simply iterate through the loop in reverse. This way you delete elements from the end as necessary, which won't displace elements that you haven't iterated through.

We can do this by converting your enumeration to a list, and wrapping this list with `reversed`:

```
for k1,v1 in reversed(list(enumerate(value['match']))):
    if k1 != '':
        print '\n Category: ',k1,' ',v1['category']

        print 'Do you want to change the class of entity',k1 ,'? Y/N', 'Or delete', k1, '1/0' 
        choice = raw_input()
        if choice == 'N' or choice == 'n':
            pass
        elif choice == 'Y' or choice == 'y' :
            print '\tEnter class : \t'
            v1['category'] = raw_input()
            tagged = string.replace(sentence, key, v1['category'])
            tagged_ans.append(tagged)
        elif choice == '1':
            del v1['category']
            del value['match'][k1]
```

Because we're casting it to a list, be careful about using this on extremely large sequences. If necessary, there are more efficient ways to do this without creating a list (such as `itertools`).

Comment: thanks but got this error : TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence